# Trouble with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to make the following Facebook graph api call...

https://graph.facebook.com/me&access_token=mytokenhere

I have been making this exact same call for months now with no issue.  I am getting the following response back...

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: me&access_token=mytokenhere",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

Obviously mytokenhere is replaced with my actual token, not passing the literal 'mytokenhere'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not calling the qs parameter correctly.

Try this:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=mytokenhere

Comment: Thank you, looks like that solved my problem.  I can't help but wonder why it has been working all this time though!  Oh well, who cares, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: I've got the same problem (mistake in query: there was `.../me&` instead of `.../me?`), but it is strange, because it worked this way almost a year :)